# MS Access SQL to replicate Excel vlookup on row data and column name

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this working in Excel now, but due to the number of records, I need to move it out into Access.

Table 1:

```
| LookupValue        | Object Name | Attribute  | Data  |
|--------------------|-------------|------------|-------|
| Object1_Attribute1 | Object1     | Attribute1 | Data1 |
| Object1_Attribute2 | Object1     | Attribute2 | Data2 |
| Object2_Attribute1 | Object2     | Attribute1 | Data3 |
| Object2_Attribute2 | Object2     | Attribute2 | Data4 |
```

(in reality over 100 attributes)

Table 2 (pre-vlookup):

```
| Object Name | Attribute1 | Attribute2 |
|-------------|------------|------------|
| Object1     |            |            |
| Object2     |            |            |
```

Table 2 (post-vlookup):

```
| Object Name | Attribute1 | Attribute2 |
|-------------|------------|------------|
| Object1     | Data1      | Data2      |
| Object2     | Data3      | Data4      |
```

How do I replicate this in Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider MS Access' [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) which can take up to 255 distinct values in *Attribute* column:

```
TRANSFORM MAX(Data) As MaxData
SELECT [Object Name]
FROM mytable
GROUP BY [Object Name]
PIVOT [Attribute]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select object_name,
       max(iif(Attribute = "Attribute1", Data, null)) as Attribute1,
       max(iif(Attribute = "Attribute2", Data, null)) as Attribute2,
       . . .
from t
group by object_name;
```